# AppEngine modules on custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I plan to make a main website and a blog.

> www.domain-name.com will be my main website and blog.domain-name.com
>   will be my blog.

I am able to achieve this on my appspot domain, but on my custom domain, it doesn't work.

> https://blog-dot-domainname.appspot.com/ is showing the correct
>   webpage.

Currently blog.domain-name.com shows the exact same thing as www.domain-name.com.

Here's what I did:

dispatch.yaml file

```
dispatch:
  # Default module serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    module: default

  - url: "domain-name.com"
    module: default

  - url: "blog.domain-name.com/*"
    module: blog
```

I also setup two custom domain names on the AppEngine settings:

> CUSTOM DOMAIN NAMES
>     domain-name.com
>      blog.domain-name.com

I am using Namecheap and I setup the required CNAME alias for my bog subdomain.

Comment: and, how did it work out?

Comment: I just added an answer with a working solution for a very similar setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699282/appengine-subdomains-to-modules-without-wildcard-mapping/30954255#30954255