# App Engine (On Google Apps) Custom Domain can't remove

Tags: google-app-engine, console, google-apps

I got the error when I click 'delete' for deleting Web address

```
We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)
```

[image]

and I got this error when I try to delete google app engine from Google Apps

```
You do not have the permissions necessary to uninstall this application.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Today problem gone after I email to support and post this issue =)