# App Engine SSL for Custom Domain within Developer Console (not via Google Apps)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

When will SSL support for custom domain be available within the developer console, instead of having to go over to Google Apps?  I read somewhere it says Q3 of 2015. But seems like people have some ways of getting that to work already.  Is it a private beta feature?

Building some apps for a client and they can't get their Google Apps account to work and we already have the custom sub-domain mapped to the GAE, and just need the last piece.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the tracking issue, indeed Q3 seems to be more likely: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10794

FWIW, I detailed a bit my solution to get things working via Google Apps in this Q&A: [AppEngine subdomains to modules without wildcard mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699282/appengine-subdomains-to-modules-without-wildcard-mapping/30954255#30954255), *maybe* it can help with your customer's problems in the meantime.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping that by Q3, it'd be the earlier part, rather than the later.  Thanks for sharing your solution.  When I tried to add the App ID in Google Apps for Work, it kept on saying I didn't have the permission.  After digging everywhere...realized, in the GAE, project, App Engine, Settings, Application Setting -> Referrers needed to be the same domain as the Google Apps domain.  Hopefully this helps anyone else out there.