# Google Cloud App Engine - How to create subdomains and redirect access to another file/folder?

Tags: php, subdomain, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a PHP5.5 module created on Google Cloud's App Engine and a SQL module on Google Cloud SQL.

Here is my PHP app.yaml:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

I am really new into Google Cloud, so I need to somehow create a subdomain such as `subdomain.myapp.com` and when my users try to access `http://subdomain.myapp.com` instead of `http://myapp.com`, I want the server to "give" them the `/subdomain/index.php` file instead of the `/index.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both `myapp.com` and `subdomain.myapp.com` domains to your app in the developer console, see this Q&A: [Google cloud DNS: point naked domain to www?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826320/google-cloud-dns-point-naked-domain-to-www)

Add a `subdomain` module to your app which will serve your subdomain-specific files.

Add a `dispatch.yaml` file to dispatch requests based on the domain to their respective module, see this Q&A: [AppEngine subdomains to modules without wildcard mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699282/appengine-subdomains-to-modules-without-wildcard-mapping)

Note: if you use SSL and sessions with cross-domain navigation you'll need a wildcard certificate otherwise you'll encounter SSL errors.

You *might* be able to get away with a single module (lower instance uptime usage/costs) if you tolerate distinct paths in your urls, like this `http://subdomain.myapp.com/subdomain/index.php` - in your `/index.php` you'd need to parse the domain in the requested url and if it's a `subdomain` one then re-direct it to the distinct path instead. No dispatch file needed in this case. Not as clean as the other solution, IMHO.

Comment: Could you please comment here how to do it step-by-step (menu by menu) about your **Add both myapp.com and subdomain.myapp.com domains to your app in the developer console** instruction? Thank you

Comment: check my answer to the post I mentioned, it has the pointer to the exact Google step-by-step procedure paying attention to the quoted details. Add `myapp.com` first, then repeat steps 2-5 (and 6 if not already done as in that post) for `subdomain.myapp.com` (`www` in that procedure corresponds to your `subdomain`).